# Understanding "In Bayesian inference, the difference between data and a parameter is that one is observed (data) and one isn't (parameter)"

Tags: bayesian, inference, missing-data, parameterization, sensitivity-analysis

In his statistical rethinking course, [Richard Mclreath states "In Bayesian inference, the difference between data and a parameter is that one is observed (data) and one isn't (parameter)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrwL6t0kW2I&t=1563s)

I am fairly new to Bayesian inference, I am having a lot of trouble understanding or intuiting this statement. My current intuition is that the data interacts with the prior via the likelihood function, and the prior has a regularizing shrinkage effect on the model estimates. To provide some context to the example in the link above, Richard is demonstrating a sensitivity analysis where there is essentially a column of data where every value is missing, and implies that there is therefore a parameter that needs to be estimated for every single row in the dataset (~4000 parameters!), which I find very confusing, and yet a model can be fit to the data that produces a distribution of estimates for the missing values.

Any help understanding the quote, in general or in the context of the example, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can remove the "Bayesian" from the quotation and it will still be fully correct.  Parameters are model constructs while data are observations.  Please search our site for threads that reference [parameters and data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=parameters+data+score%3A10) for many, many examples.  The duplicate was found among the top hits.

Comment: Hi @whuber I read the linked post; it was all information I believe I already understood, and it did not help me with my question. How does that post connect to my question?

Comment: Your question appears to focus on the distinction between data and parameters.  If it's trying to ask something else, please edit it to clarify what you're looking for.  "Any help understanding the quote" is too vague to offer more specific advice at this point.